# How to melt a 60k x 60k matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, melt

When I melt a 60k x 60k matrix (i.e. only numerical values) with R using `melt` funtion of the `reshape2` package I get the following error:

```
>melt(m)

Error in if (n > 0) c(NA_integer_, -n) else integer() :    missing value
where TRUE/FALSE needed Calls: melt ... <Anonymous> -> melt.matrix ->
expand.grid -> .set_row_names In addition: Warning messages: 1: In rep.fac * nx
: NAs produced by integer overflow 2: In .set_row_names(as.integer(prod(d)))
:   NAs introduced by coercion to integer range 
Execution halted
```

The error doesn't occur for smaller (e.g. 20k x 20k) matrices, so I assume that it has to do with the matrix size. Is there any otherway to melt a matrix in a fast way?

I also tried

```
melt = data.frame(row = c(row(m)), col = c(col(m)), value = c(m))
```

but this results in a similar error

```
Error in if (mirn && nrows[i] > 0L) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In structure(value, row.names = row.names, class = "data.frame") :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
Execution halted
```

Comment: If your matrix were called `m`, you could try `data.frame(row = c(row(m)), col = c(col(m)), value = c(m))`

Comment: You could also try `tidyr::gather`.

Comment: Is it sure that your memory can handle another `2 * 6e4*6e4` "integer" values + your `6e4*6e4` "matrix"? If so, a way to avoid multiple copies of large vectors is `list(i = rep_len(seq_len(nrow(mat)), length(mat)), j = rep(seq_len(ncol(mat)), each = nrow(mat)), x = "dim<-"(mat, NULL))` and treat the "list" as if it were a "data.frame". This just creates the necessary vectors and, possibly, sets the "dim" attribute to `NULL` without copying `mat`

Comment: How about `library(Matrix);summary(Matrix(m, sparse = TRUE))`

Comment: `data.frame(row = c(row(m)), col = c(col(m)), value = c(m))` also produces an error (see above). I am trying `library(Matrix)` now

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can split the object into two smaller ones, melt them separately to avoid the overflow error. Then use rbind to join the resulting melted data.

```
m1 <- m[1:30000,]
m2 <- m[30001:nrow(m),]
mymelt1 <- melt(m1, na.rm = TRUE)
mymelt2 <- melt(m12, na.rm = TRUE)
mymelt <- rbind(mymelt1, mymelt2)
remove(mymelt1)
remove(mymelt2)
```